# How to create multi-type Array using template programming

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

We can create a multi-type array using void* or void** ,
For an example - 
(In "C programming also in C++ programming")

```
    #define ARRAY_LENGTH 47
    void *ptr;
    void **arr = malloc(sizeof(void *) * ARRAY_LENGTH);
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_LENGTH; i++) {
    arr[i] = ptr;
}
free(arr);
```

Therefore we can cast any pointer type to void* type and store addresses in void** and cast it back from array to use them appropriately.
Like wise,In modern C++ do we have any elegant approach to create such an array for storing multi-type(pointers) using template programming?
Please provide us simple example(without using boost library).
Thank you.

Comment: `boost::variant`? `boost::any`? `boost::type_erasure::any`?

Comment: `boost::any` is suitable.

Comment: Without boost? if we want to do our own implementation?

Comment: Why would you want to roll your own if it is something that's already implemented in a high quality library? Or does this happen to be a learning exercise?

Comment: Yeah I really want learn how these things implemented with template type deduction/

Comment: So you need to implement it from scratch?

Comment: Yeah,Could you provide proper example ?

Answer (score 0):

c++11 has `std::tuple`.

Have you considered this?

"Modern C++ Design" by A. Alexandrescu discusses typelists in chapter 3. Maybe this will be useful.